# Json extract - script faills to extract just one of the fields

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, json-extract

I have this mmysql query that extracts all of the fields properly, save for the 'code' field, which comes up null throughout in the results.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
select id, guid,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].lang')) as lang,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].startDate')) as start_date,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].isStartDateComputed')) as is_start_date_computed,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].reportedDate')) as reported_date,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].governmentLevelType')) as govt_level_type,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].governmentLevelTypeGuid')) as govt_level_type_guid,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].jurisdictionLevel')) as jdx_level,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].jurisdictionLevelGuid')) as jdx_level_guid,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].codedSubjectMatterType')) as coded_subject_matter_type,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].codedSubjectMatterTypeGuid')) as coded_subject_matter_type_guid,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].code')) as code,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].codedGovernmentSystem')) as coded_govt_system,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].codedGovernmentSystemGuid')) as coded_govt_system_guid,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].codedGeographicTerritory')) as coded_geo_territory,
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].codedGeographicTerritoryGuid')) as coded_geo_territory_guid
```

from courts
;

Here is a sample array that I'm trying to extract data from:

```
"jurisdictions" : "[{\"lang\": \"en\", \"startDate\": \"2012-04-10\", \"isStartDateComputed\": true, \"governmentLevelType\": \"State\", \"governmentLevelTypeGuid\": \"urn:propertyValueItem:0D85EC301A4A461AB8A71270D40E9FE5\", \"jurisdictionLevel\": \"Intermediate Appeals\", \"codedRepresentation\": {\"codedSubjectMatterTypeGuid\": \"urn:propertyValueItem:7E1B0257EFFB4A4BA6E6672158B105E1\", \"code\": \"US-TN.APL-CRM.EGD\", \"codedGovernmentSystemGuid\": \"urn:propertyValueItem:1F1D25A1D9A24D699499B678DA2CBEAF\", \"codedGeographicTerritoryGuid\": \"urn:propertyValueItem:A99D07C64F004068B213206A364FCC3C\", \"codedGeographicTerritory\": \"EGD\", \"codedSubjectMatterType\": \"APL-CRM\", \"codedGovernmentSystem\": \"US-TN\"}, \"geopoliticalBodies\": [], \"jurisdictionLevelGuid\": \"urn:propertyValueItem:53B0C6AF9A68462A98D7B49F3A9014F0\", \"reportedDate\": \"2018-12-18\"}]",
```

For some reason, I get everything I want, except that I get nothing back from this line:

```
json_unquote(json_extract(jurisdictions, '$[0].codedRepresentation[0].code')) as code,
```

When I should get back (based on the sample data I provided above):

```
US-TN.APL-CRM.EGD
```

I'm not sure why this is happening for just this field, but any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7475aa3aad3f10111c1317f8212c9e15).